# I Need Help Alignin 2 TD in My Email Signature HTML

Tags: html, email, html-email, signature

For some time I've been developing this simple HTML code to use it as my signature email. Recently I've add the .gif photo and links to make it look better. I can't put the Instagram icon and the WhatsApp icon side by side, I've tried a lot of things on the internet, but didn't managed to make it.

Here's the code for my HTML signature.

[this is a screenshot of my signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VoN5.png)

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 590px;">
    <tbody><tr>

        <td style="border-right: 2px solid #a9a9a9; padding-right: 0px; vertical-align:middle" valign="middle"><a href="https://beattor.com.br/"><img id="BeattorLogo" data-class="external" src="https://beattor.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Gif-Assinatura-do-Email-2.gif" height="150px" walt="Beattor Comunicacao" style="display: block"></a></td>

        <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                        <font style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">Thiago Dam</font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-bottom: 5px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                        <font style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">CEO e Diretor Comercial</font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
    
    <tr>
                    <td style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt;"><font style="color: #333333; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Verdana">Site:&nbsp;<a href="https://beattor.com.br/" style="color: #06c">beattor.com.br</a></font></td>
                </tr>
    
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt;"><font style="color: #333333; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Verdana">Email:&nbsp;<a href="mailto:thiago.dam@beattor.com.br" style="color: #06c">thiago.dam@beattor.com.br</a></font></td>
                </tr>
    
    <tr>
                    <td style="padding-right: 100px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt;"><font style="color: #333333; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Verdana">Contato:&nbsp;<font style="color: #333333; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Verdana"><a href="tel:21964079707" style="color: #06c">(21) 96407-9707</a></font></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-right: 100px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt;"><font style="color: #333333; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Verdana">&nbsp;<font style="color: #333333; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Verdana"></font></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                   <td style="padding-right: 100px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt;"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/abeattor/"><img id="InstagramLogo" data-class="external" src="https://beattor.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Instagram-Logo-Beattor-Comunicacao.png"  height="30px" walt="Instagram da Beattor" style="display: block"></a>
                   </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                   <td style=" font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt;"><a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5521964079707&text=Ol%C3%A1,%20tudo%20bem%3F%20Eu%20gostaria%20de%20mais%20informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20sobre%20a%20Beattor%20Comunicacao"><img id="WhatsApp Logo" data-class="external" src="https://beattor.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/WhatsApp-Logo-Beattor-Comunicacao.png"  height="30px" walt="WhatsApp da Beattor" style="display: block"></a>
                   </td>
               </tr>      
            </tr> 
            

            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want both your social icons on the same line, one way of doing it would be to firstly remove the closing row `</tr>`/ opening new line `<tr>` between them (I've done so in the snippet. After that, float your icons left in the social icon tds (add `float:left;` into your style with the font-size and family) and then you should be good to go. I added a small margin-left (10px)  to the whatsapp one to put a small space between them. I also removed the 100px padding from the instagram.

Hope this helps!

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 590px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td style="border-right: 2px solid #a9a9a9; padding-right: 0px; vertical-align:middle" valign="middle">
        <a href="https://beattor.com.br/"><img id="BeattorLogo" data-class="external" src="https://beattor.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Gif-Assinatura-do-Email-2.gif" height="150px" walt="Beattor Comunicacao" style="display: block"></a>
      </td>

      <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px;">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                <font style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">Thiago Dam</font>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-bottom: 5px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                <font style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">CEO e Diretor Comercial</font>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt;">
                <font style="color: #333333; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Verdana">Site:&nbsp;<a href="https://beattor.com.br/" style="color: #06c">beattor.com.br</a></font>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt;">
                <font style="color: #333333; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Verdana">Email:&nbsp;<a href="mailto:thiago.dam@beattor.com.br" style="color: #06c">thiago.dam@beattor.com.br</a></font>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td style="padding-right: 100px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt;">
                <font style="color: #333333; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Verdana">Contato:&nbsp;
                  <font style="color: #333333; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Verdana"><a href="tel:21964079707" style="color: #06c">(21) 96407-9707</a></font>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td style="padding-right: 50px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt;">
                <font style="color: #333333; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Verdana">&nbsp;
                  <font style="color: #333333; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Verdana"></font>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td style="font-family: Verdana; float:left; font-size: 10pt;">
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/abeattor/"><img id="InstagramLogo" data-class="external" src="https://beattor.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Instagram-Logo-Beattor-Comunicacao.png" height="30px" walt="Instagram da Beattor" style="display:block; "></a>
              </td>
            
              <td style="font-family: Verdana; margin-left:10px; float:left; font-size: 10pt;">
                <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5521964079707&text=Ol%C3%A1,%20tudo%20bem%3F%20Eu%20gostaria%20de%20mais%20informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20sobre%20a%20Beattor%20Comunicacao"><img id="WhatsApp Logo" data-class="external" src="https://beattor.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/WhatsApp-Logo-Beattor-Comunicacao.png" height="30px" walt="WhatsApp da Beattor" style="display:block;"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
    </tr>


    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot from the bottom of my heart! You helped me alot!
I couldn't figure out what to do.

You really solved this issue. Thanks a lot! =D

Comment: <td> elements naturally 'float' (although not in the same way) so I'm not sure why you felt this was necessary. It sounds like just the fixing of the rows did it. Remove `float: left` because that isn't a valid attribute for `<td>` elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rachel! I dind't know how to accept the answer.